# Заполнение строки случайными символами

Tags: c++

Как заполнить строку случайными маленькими русскими буквами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Заведи массив символов - русский алфавит.
Дальше с помощью генератора случайных чисел генерируй индекс из этого массива и по нему выводи символ.

Ночь на дворе и это то, что сходу пришло в голову)

Comment: можно на примере пожалуйста?

Comment: ну массив заполнить русскими маленькими буквами можешь?)))
дальше почитай вот это:
http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=15

Comment: недавно начал изучать язык

Comment: поздравляю)
в чем проблема то?
1)Создаёшь массив чаров alphabet на 33 символа. 
2)Дальше ручками заполняешь это дело. 
3) Дальше генерируешь случайное число rand от нуля до 32 (это один из индексов массива)
4) alphabet[rand] - твой случайный символ

Comment: Массив чаров? Ой, а у меня linux и utf-8. И что мне делать?

Comment: @alexlz: массив строк, или массив `wchar_t` если utf-8 не догма.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
const char * ar[] = {"а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с",
        "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я"};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n;
    string  s = "";
    stringstream ss (argv[1]);
    ss >> n;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) s += ar[rand() % (sizeof ar/sizeof (char *))];
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

UPD Поправлено по рекомендации [[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)

Comment: Вот это четкий код)

Comment: И что это за г-код на 5-й строке?

Comment: Где именно?

Comment: @GLmonster это строка продолжения инициализации ar?

Comment: Я о том, что создавать 33 строки из одного символа в динамической памяти - это бред. Лучше уж замени это на:

    char ar[]="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

Comment: @GLmonster Кому лучше? Как мне найти букву "б" в массиве ar? Или букву "в"?

Кстати, совет насчёт `L'а'+rand()%33` -- он тоже забавно-неправильный.

Comment: В твоём коде я ничего utf-шного не вижу. И строки самые обычные - std::string. А если нужен UTF-8, то можно примерно как у тебя, только вместо string - const char*.

 Причём тут utf-8? Это символ из двухбайтового Юникода.

Comment: Нет ничего utf-ного -- и ладно. Однако работает. И будет работать, даже если к маленьким русским добавить какие-то более длинные буквы. Насчёт `const char*` -- согласен. Насчёт L'а' -- почему из двухбайтного?

Comment: L'а' имеет тип wchar_t, который занимает два байта. То есть значением этого типа можно закодировать первые 65536 символов Юникода.

Comment: Про два байта -- откуда дровишки? У меня WCHAR_MAX = 2147483647l, а оно в два байта не лезет.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая таблица символов ANSI, которую можно увидеть тут
[пример таблицы](http://labkit.ru/html/Assembler_for_PIC?id=377).

У каждого символа есть свой код от 0 до 255. И русские буквы (большие и маленькие) выпадают от 192 до 255, соответственно только большие от 192 до 223, а только маленькие от 224 до 255.

Создаем массив типа char, заполняем его русскими символами и в итоге по случайному индексу нашего массива выводим символы на экран :)

Также можно сделать просто массив типа int и заполнить его кодами символов, а при выводе ставить (char), результат будет тот же.

Для случайного вывода нужно подключить time.h, реализовать случайность в определенном диапазоне можно с помощью такого алгоритма rand() % (МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ - МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ + 1) + МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ.

В итоге вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

// макрос, который выводит случайные числа в определенном диапазоне
// rand() % (МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ - МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ + 1) + МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ
#define _rand(min, max) ( rand() % ((max) - (min) + 1) + (min) )

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    srand(time(NULL));

    char chars[32]; // наш алфавит

    // заполняем массив
    for(int i=224, n=0; i<=255; ++i, ++n)
    {
        chars[n] = (char) i; // (char) приводит код к символу
    }

    // выводим собранный массив
    std::cout << "Собранный массив:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<32; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << chars[i] << "\t";
    }

    // выводим собранный массив в случайном порядке
    std::cout << "\nСлучайным образом:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << chars[_rand(0, 31)] << "\t";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ябы еще прописал namespace sdt)

Comment: После добавления #include <stdlib.h> и запуска
    
    Собранный массив:
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � �   � � � � � � � � �
    � � � �
    Случайным образом:
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
    � � � �

И, кстати, что такое "таблица символов ANSI" и откуда американский институт стандартов знает русские буквы? Наши разведчики подсуетились?

Comment: в консоли используется ASCII код он состоит из символов в 1байт(0-255) первыя часть(128) это американский стандарт  а вторая часть национальная... http://school497.ru/download/u/02/img/asc1.gif

для работы вывода русских букв подрубаем setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

Comment: setlocale подрубать под корень или можно выше (не обращая внимания на высоту пенька)? В ответе @belka вообще задаются коды символов в одной из кодировок (cp1251?). А у меня -- utf-8

Comment: подрубать до использования (сразу после **main(){**) 

также требует библиотеку **locale.h** || **locale** 

работает только на вывод ... 

собственно setlocale подрубает к аски национальную часть...

но лучший вариант в винде это **SetConsoleCP(1251);** + **SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);** из библеотеки **Windows.h**

Answer (score 2):

[@skies](/users/7836/skies), Вам написали кучу советов в ответах и комментариях (есть получше и похуже).

Думаю, что если Вам нужна простая программа, то она будет платформозависимой (т.е. Вы знаете кодировку русского языка (хотя бы она однобайтная, UTF-8 или юникод) в Вашей системе и пишете для нее. Можете уточнить в вопросе, для какой ОС Вы хотите программу и получить конкретный совет.

В любом случае Вам нужен массив маленьких русских букв. Для простой программы скорее всего это массив указателей на строки из одной буквы (строки в терминах Си, а не С++) (для utf-8 (как в ответе [@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz))) в строке будет 3 байта (включая завершающий ее '\0').  При таком решении Вы будете использовать один и тот же алгоритм вывода/вставки русских букв, независимо от кодировки.

В программе, максимально независимой от системы (Windows, Mac, *nix, (настроена/не настроена локализация) и компилятора, внутри программы видимо удобней всего использовать массив типа int с Unicode. Перед выводом придется (динамически) определить текущую кодировку русского языка и самому перекодировать юникод в нее (это нужно для работы с ненастоенной локализацией).

Подход не общепринятый, потому что достаточно сложный. К сожалению корректно сделать это не всегда возможно. Например, у пользователя Ubuntu работает в utf-8, но в конкретном окне gnome-terminal может быть установлена, скажем, кодировка cp-1251 (при этом остается LANG=ru_RU.utf8).

Comment: Что значит "(динамически) определить текущую кодировку"?

Comment: прочитать переменную `LANG`, например.

Comment: Это примерно так?

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iconv.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main() {
      int c;
      char    s[3];
      char *loc = getenv("LANG");
      char *dot = strchr(loc, '.');
      iconv_t cd = iconv_open(dot+1, "ucs-2");
      for(c = L'а'; c <= L'я'; c++) {
        size_t ins = 2, outs = 2;
        char   *in = (char *) &c, *out = s;
        int i = iconv(cd, &in, &ins, &out, &outs);
        s[2-outs] = 0;
        printf("%s", s);
      }
      iconv_close(cd);
      return 0;
    }

Кстати, тут может и всплыть little/big endian.

Comment: Динамически определять кодировку - ну, в простом случае по LANG. Зависит от ОС. В  винде, например, использовать LANG не принято. 

Вообще смотрим (приоритеты зависят от разработчика) setlocale(LC_ALL,""), LANG, анализируем ругань popen("mkdir /","r") тип ОС ... и принимаем решение (иногда неожиданное iso 8859-5 если мы в hp-ux)

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой кроссплатформенный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifdef WIN32
#define RUSLOCAL "rus"
#elif __unix
#define RUSLOCAL "ru_RU.utf-8"  
#endif

wchar_t randomletter() {
    static  bool seedset = false;   
    if (!seedset) {
        srand(static_cast<unsigned> (time(NULL)));
        seedset = true; 
    }
    static wchar_t alph[] = L"абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя";
    return alph [rand() % (sizeof(alph) / sizeof (alph[0]) - 1)];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  locale::global (locale( RUSLOCAL ));
  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    wcout << randomletter() <<  L"  ";
  }
  wcout << endl;

#ifdef WIN32
  system ("PAUSE");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Тестировано в Линуксе g++ и в винде VC++ 2010. Если используются в винде прекомпилированные заголовки, надо еще stdafx.h включить.

Comment: @mikillskegg, к сожалению в MinGW g++ (g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) в Win 7 даже не транслируется



    rusl.c:21:29: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
    rusl.c: In function `wchar_t randomletter()':
    rusl.c:22: warning: division by zero in `rand() % 0'
    rusl.c: In function `int main(int, char**)':
    rusl.c:29: error: `wcout' was not declared in this scope
    rusl.c:31: error: `wcout' was not declared in this scope


а вот в Ubuntu 

    к  о  э  м  у  о  л  щ  в  у

похоже на ОК.

Comment: Может, потому что версия gcc старая. Я пробовал с cygwin (gcc 4.3). Если изначальный текст программы сохраняется в utf-8, то компилируется. Но при запуске программа вылетает с ошибкой неправильной локали. В общем, мрак какой-то.

Comment: Да, **действительно** кроссплатформенный код **с русскими буквами** это полный мрак. 

По хорошему в винде еще надо смотреть выводим в консоль или  в файл (пайп), а для консоли что там cp866 или cp1251. Сделать можно, но простыня с \#ifdef-ами получается будь здоров.

Comment: Поставил последнюю версию MinGW. Собралось без проблем, но при запуске также выбрасывает. Покопался: у него отсутствует русская локаль в принципе. Вот такая веселуха. 

Вывод: Ну эту винду нафиг.

Comment: Но в VS все нормально отработало.

Comment: Вопрос становится интересным. Раньше были какие-то "Russion_Russia.1251" и пр., но тут на неё ругается.

Answer (score 0):

Массивы для получения случайной буквы не нужны: 'а'+rand()%33

Comment: Исчо адын... Во-первых 8-бит/не 8-бит. Во-вторых я, например, не помню в ДКОИ-8 (8-бит кодировка, на основе EBCDIC) русские маленькие идут подряд или нет.

Comment: Если не 1 байт, а 2 байта на символ, то тогда L'а'+rand()%33
 И вообще, зачем все кодировки подряд поддерживать? Да и вопрос вроде не ты задавал, а требований таких в нём нет.

Comment: Так, не нравится. Все кодировки зачем, да? А ещё (если 2 байта) все архитектуры зачем (с little-endian или big-endian)?

Вопрос, конечно, задавал не я, а @skies, но мне уже комментарий оставить нельзя? А условий в вопросе вообще никаких не оговаривалось

Comment: >Все кодировки зачем, да?

 Да, зачем? Бери какой-нибудь Юникод и используй везде.

>А ещё (если 2 байта) все архитектуры зачем (с little-endian или big-endian)?

 И как big\low endian повлияют на поддержку архитектурами?

Comment: @GLmonster "Какой-нибудь юникод" -- это хорошо. Какой? Мелкомягкие в прошлом тысячелетии выбрали один, потом пришлось его плавно перелопачивать в другой...

А насчёт big/low -- так ведь при арифметических операциях можно и задом наперёд сохранить. (Кстати, можно напомнить про инетовские htonl, ntohl, htons, ntohs)

Comment: @GLmonster, ни в одной известной мне кодировке из-за буквы **`ё`** правильно  работать не будет (даже если заменить %33 на %34).

У этой **`ё`**-*буквы* всюду код вне диапазона 'а'-'я'.

Answer (score 0):

В псевдокоде алгоритм для заполнения массива случайными маленькими русскими буквами будет следующий:

**1**. Генерируем случайное число RANDcode в диапазоне MINcode до MAXcode. Здесь MINcode это минимальный код для русской маленькой буквы, а MAXcode соответственно максимальный код для маленькой русской буквы.

**2**. Заносим в массив число RANDcode.

**3**. Если массив еще не заполнен, то переходим на шаг 1.

Чтобы сгенерировать случайное число в диапазоне от MINcode до MAXcode, можно воспользоваться функцией iRand (см. статью "[Генерация случайного числа в нужном диапазоне](http://microsin.net/programming/PC/rand-number-in-range.html)"). Остается определиться только со значениями MINcode и MAXcode - они зависят от кодировки. Например, если применяется кодировка **КОИ-8R**, то MINcode=0xC0, MAXcode=0xDF; а если применяется кодировка **CP1251**, то MINcode=0xE0, MAXcode=0xFF.

В общем случае, если не нужно заморачиваться с кодировкой, то сначала надо подготовить массив ALLRUSSMALLLETTERS, где будут перечислены все маленькие русские буквы, и генерировать случайное число для индекса этого массива (от 0 до sizeof(ALLRUSSMALLLETTERS)-1). По случайному индексу из массива ALLRUSSMALLLETTERS нужно брать символ, и вставлять его в заполняемый массив.

Answer (score 0):

1. задать в ручную требуемый набор символов (массив)
2. получить его размер
3. создать функцию возвращающую случайный символ (рандом из диапазона количества символов)

вариант с локалями и т.д. не стОит, это само по себе уже задача. Кроссплатформенность в этом случае выдерживается. Если вдруг, консоль будет выдавать кракозябли - пинаем консоль или юзера. Например, перед вызовом в Windows из cmd можно установить локаль.. Если в никсах её нет - пусть думает об этом юзер. Как то так, варианты кода уже дали и много.

Comment: Больше всего заинтересовало предложение пинать юзера. А если он недоступен или доступен, но слишком здоровый?

Comment: Пиная юзера, теряешь деньги.(С)

Comment: А если ты сам и  есть этот юзер?

Comment: Теряешь время, а значит и деньги, нервы и вообще радость жизни.

Comment: ребята, выражение "пинать юзера" не стоит понимать дословно..
это значит, потребовать пользователя выполнить условия, например, если он хочет видеть русский текст, то, позаботиться о локале.. В данном обсуждении, как я понял, задача на уровне обучения, а значит, пользователь - программист - студент, может легко перевести консоль в нужную кодировку.
Это я к тому, что заботиться о универсальности программы - может завести в такие дебри, что будет забыта сама цель программы.